# .net Standard 2.0 class library produce error when adding reference

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, class-library

Created a .net Standard 2.0 class library, and then used it in a console  application created by targetting .netframework 4.6.1 and dot net core 2.1. when running web application the blow exception was thrown.

Could not load file or assembly 'ChoETL.JSON.Core, Version=1.1.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tested same library with  project reference in .net core web application and there was no error. when try with published DLL it show error in both core and framework application

Dotnet standard class library project file is

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
     <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="ChoETL.JSON.NETStandard" Version="1.1.0.5-beta3" />
      <PackageReference Include="ChoETL.NETStandard" Version="1.1.0.5-beta3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
     </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

early when adding project reference is .netframework 4.6.1 it show same error, then adding following setting in property group (project file) it disappear

```
<DependsOnNETStandard>true</DependsOnNETStandard>
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle> 
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
```

and is there any proper way to publish dotnet standard libary to work both .netframework 4.6.1 and dot net core 2.1

Comment: this *should* just be picked up and work as a transitive dependency (you shouldn't even need the ChoETL.NETStandard dependency, since ChoETL.JSON.NETStandard should add it transitively); what build tooling are you using in your .NET Framework project? Note: 4.6.1 is a bit dodgy... the loader is *especially* bad there, but frankly there are a *lot* of problems with .NET Framework consuming .NET Standard; things get better in .NET Framework 4.7.2 and 4.8, but [it is still tricky](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/01/net-core-net-5-exodus-of-net-framework.html)

Comment: in particular: there's a *big* difference between "I'm using an old version of Visual Studio and old-style cspoj targeting net461", and "I'm using the latest Visual Studio / .NET Core command-line tools, with a new-style csproj that targets net461"

Comment: i removed ChoETL.NETStandard dependency, still same error